# Prove that G and G' are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=$ the set of $2\times 2$ matrices 
$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} a& b\\ 0& a-2b\end{bmatrix}\;\middle\vert\; a,b \in\mathbb{R} \text{ and }A^2\neq 2ab\right\},$$ where the group operation is matrix multiplication. Let 
$$G'=\{(c,d) \mid c,d \in\mathbb{R} \text{ and } c,d \neq 0\}$$ with group operation $(c_1,d_1)(c_2,d_2)=(c_1c_2,d_1d_2)$. Prove that  $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: When you write, "$A^2\ne2ab$", what's $A$? a typo for $a$?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $A$ is just $a$.
Now send $\begin{bmatrix} a& b\\ 0& a-2b\end{bmatrix}$ to the pair $(a, a-2b)$. So you have only to verify this is an isomorphism. Notice that this map is of course bijective, hence the only task is its homomorphism property, which you can verify by matrix multiplication.